# Chrome extension, because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive but only after refreshing window

Tags: html, google-chrome, content-security-policy

I made a chrome extension that loads an iframe on the gmail url. So far so good!
When I install the extension it loads the I framed with no problems but here comes the problem. If I refresh or access gmail again it doesn't work anymore with the following error, and no other  errors.

> Refused to frame 'https://...........com/' because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'
> https://clients4.google.com/insights/consumersurveys/
> https://calendar.google.com/accounts/ https://ogs.google.com
> https://onegoogle-autopush.sandbox.google.com
> https://accounts.google.com/ https://apis.google.com/u/
> https://apis.google.com/_/streamwidgets/
> https://clients6.google.com/static/
> https://content.googleapis.com/static/
> https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/
> https://www.google.com/calendar/ https://calendar.google.com/calendar/
> https://docs.google.com/ https://drive.google.com
> https://*.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/
> https://feedback.googleusercontent.com/resources/
> https://www.google.com/tools/feedback/
> https://support.google.com/inapp/
> https://*.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/ifr
> https://hangouts.google.com/ https://talkgadget.google.com/
> https://*.talkgadget.google.com/
> https://www-gm-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/
> https://plus.google.com/ https://wallet.google.com/gmail/
> https://www.youtube.com/embed/
> https://clients5.google.com/pagead/drt/dn/
> https://clients5.google.com/ads/measurement/jn/
> https://www.gstatic.com/mail/ww/ https://www.gstatic.com/mail/intl/
> https://clients5.google.com/webstore/wall/
> https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/ https://workspace.google.com/u/
> https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/appfinder
> https://gsuite.google.com/u/
> https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/appfinder
> https://www.gstatic.com/mail/promo/ https://notifications.google.com/
> https://tracedepot-pa.clients6.google.com/static/
> https://staging-taskassist-pa-googleapis.sandbox.google.com
> https://taskassist-pa.clients6.google.com
> https://*.prod.amp4mail.googleusercontent.com/
> https://*.client-channel.google.com/client-channel/client
> https://clients4.google.com/invalidation/lcs/client
> https://tasks.google.com/embed/ https://keep.google.com/companion
> https://addons.gsuite.google.com
> https://contacts.google.com/widget/hovercard/v/2
> https://gsuite.google.com
> https://*.googleusercontent.com/confidential-mail/attachments/".

Now. You are wondering if I put the CSP in my header. The answer is yes. I have header("Content-Security-Policy: frame-src 'self' https://*.google.com;"); in my php and the header si loaded. But the question I can't answer is: **Is Chrome seeing errors after the page refresh and why?**

In theory if there is a problem in the CSP it should block the iframe from the first moment, and not after a while.
Do you know anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

> Refused to frame 'https://...........com/' because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' ... Google's domains here ...

It's not your CSP, but some of Google's iframe publish its own. Because commonly Google does not allow to embed own into third-party.
Most interesting part: 'https://...........com/' is hidden (is here your domain or not?).

> Is Chrome seeing errors after the page refresh and why?

Google's services based on a lot of it own iframes, wich inter each other based on Cookie.
For example, you can embed `https://gmail.com` into iframe, but if you are **logged** into account (have auth Cookies), Gmail does auto redirect you to `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/` page which does not allow iframing (because of `X-Frame-Options deny`).

Behavior of iframes of Google could be very complicated, so a exact answer "Why" is not possible without detail researches.

Anyway embed of Google services (not officially intended for embedding) into iframe is not a good idea. Google does not allow that because of security.