# How to create events with google calendar api using a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

**Goal:** To create a google calendar event using a chrome extension.

I have been stuck for hours to find a solution to call the google calendar api from my popup script. However, I keep getting the following error:

> Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' [https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"](https://apis.google.com/js/api.js%22). Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

The calendar api works if I use the example given on the official docs (https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js). However, in this example the api script is loaded using the script tag in a html file and it does not encounter the above issue for reasons I do not fully understand.

My Manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
  
    "name": "",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "identity","*://apis.google.com/*"
      ],
    "content_scripts":[
        {   "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
        }
      ],
    "browser_action":{
      "default_icon":"icon.png",
      "default_popup":"popup.html",
      "default_title":"A popup will come here"
    },
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com/js/api.js; object-src 'self'"
    

    
  }
```

My popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>GTmetrix Analyzer</title>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="authorize_button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
  <button id="signout_button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

</body>

</html>
```

My popup.js

```
// Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
var CLIENT_ID ="";
var API_KEY = "";

// Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
var DISCOVERY_DOCS = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest",
];

// Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
// included, separated by spaces.
var SCOPES =
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";

var authorizeButton = document.getElementById("authorize_button");
var signoutButton = document.getElementById("signout_button");

function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.load("client:auth2", initClient);
}

function initClient() {
  gapi.client
    .init({
      apiKey: API_KEY,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      scope: SCOPES,
    })
    .then(
      function () {
        // Listen for sign-in state changes.
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

        // Handle the initial sign-in state.
        updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
        authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
        signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
      },
      function (error) {
        appendPre(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
      }
    );
}
/**
 *  Sign in the user upon button click.
 */
function handleAuthClick(event) {
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
}

/**
 *  Sign out the user upon button click.
 */
function handleSignoutClick(event) {
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
}

function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
  if (isSignedIn) {
    authorizeButton.style.display = "none";
    signoutButton.style.display = "block";
    createEvent();
  } else {
    authorizeButton.style.display = "block";
    signoutButton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function createEvent() {
  var event = {
    summary: "Google I/O 2015",
    location: "800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103",
    description: "A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.",
    start: {
      dateTime: "2021-08-22T09:00:00-07:00",
      timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles",
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: "2021-08-22T17:00:00-07:00",
      timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles",
    },
  };

  gapi.client.calendar.events
    .insert({
      calendarId: "primary",
      resource: event,
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      appendPre("Event created: " + response.result.htmlLink);
      console.log(response);
    });
}


let script = document.createElement('script');
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab){
    script.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/api.js";
    document.body.append(script);

})

script.addEventListener('load',function(){
  handleClientLoad();
})
```

Note: I would also be interested to know if there is a better way of making this type of chrome extension than what I am currently doing. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64670820/1841839

Comment: @DaImTo not a similiar issue. Thanks!

Comment: Try replacing `https://apis.google.com/js/api.js` with `https://apis.google.com` in the CSP field of the manifest